# How do I detect if Microsoft Project is installed in my Wix installer package?

Tags: wix, installation, vsto, add-in, ms-project

I am migrating a VS 2010 Project Add-in to VS 2013.  In the process, because they got rid of the built-in installer in 2013, I am changing my installation package to Wix.  I have already done this for my Outlook add-in.  In the Outlook add-in installation Bundle I used this block of code to check for Outlook prerequisites:

```
<util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2010" Guid="CFF13DD8-6EF2-49EB-B265-E3BFC6501C1D" Variable="Outlook2010"/>
<util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2010PIA" Guid="1D844339-3DAE-413E-BC13-62D6A52816B2" Variable="Outlook2010PIA"/>
<util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2013" Guid="F9F828D5-9F0B-46F9-9E3E-9C59F3C5E136" Variable="Outlook2013"/>
<bal:Condition Message="This Setup need Outlook 2010 or 2013 to be installed">
  Outlook2010 OR Outlook2010PIA OR Outlook2013
</bal:Condition>
```

This is working great so I'm trying to do the same thing for MS Project but I am having little luck finding the appropriate Component ID values to use to find Project 2010/2013.  Will someone please help me?

Also, another question regarding the PIA. If "Outlook2010PIA" is true, should that be enough to continue?  I copied this from an example elsewhere and found that odd.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can get access to a system where Project is installed or get a copy of the MSI files (maybe a few flavors) you could look in the Component table with Orca and hope to find a standard component. On a system with Project installed there's cached MSI file with an odd name in Windows\installer, and it's tedious but floating the mouse often tell you the product name, so you can open that with Orca.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to find the component IDs in the msi files as suggested.